# iOS: scrolling everything but navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uinavigationbar

I have a `UIViewController` which conforms to a `UITabBarController`, so I can't add a navigation controller before it. In my view I have a `UITableView` which is too small so you can't really see the cells when you click the `UITextField`in them and the keyboard comes up. With that in mind, I inserted in my `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];
CGRect frame = self.view.frame; frame.origin.y = -120;
[self.view setFrame:frame]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That way, everything scrolls up, and it solves my problem of not being able to see the cells, however I have a `UINavigationBar` which I don't want to scroll. What do I do?

btw, I can't make it a `UITableViewController` because not all of the screen is a `UITableView`

thanks!

Comment: use scrollview and scroll that scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You have used UIVIewController ,just start the scroller where the navigation bar end in the UISTORYBOARD. It will make the navigation bar non scrollable.